# Using router identity as an exit condition for a simple client/server program

Tags: c, zeromq

I have two separate C programs using CZMQ. One is a client and one is a server. The server transfers data from a file to the client, which writes the data received to a new file, called "testdata_out." Once the client receives the final chunk of data from the server, the client exits.

The problem is that the server sits there, waiting to send more data to the client, but the client program has exited completely. I've had a look in GDB and the server just gets stuck at

```
zframe_t *identity = zframe_recv( router );
```

I've done detailed logging using fprintf() to confirm that this is the case.

I'm using the [ZMQ File transfer model 3](http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:fileio3) as my example - I've copied the exact code and test it to make sure it works as well.

Basically I'm looking for ideas - what can I use as an exit condition if identity validation doesn't work? **Could I send an abort signal somehow, since I can't edit the ZeroMQ function 'zframe_recv?' Or if someone can see what the problem is with my code or setup, a fix that lets me use ID validation as an exit condition would be awesome.**

Here's the server function:

```
int zmq_send_internal_file( struct arg_struct *args )
{
   struct arg_struct *input = (struct arg_struct *)args;
   int node_num = input->node;
   const char *fp = input->file_name;
   int chunkNum = 0;
   FILE *file_to_xfer = fopen( fp, "r" );
   zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new( );
   void *router = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_ROUTER);

   //two parts per msg so HWM is size PIPELINE * 2
   zsocket_set_hwm (router, PIPELINE * 2);
   char *complete_address = "tcp://127.0.0.1:6000";
   if( 0 == zsocket_connect (router, complete_address ) )
   {
       printf("logging here\n");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("logging here\n");
   }
   while (true)
   {
        //what if we don't check the sender identity as a breaking condition?
        //what if we check chunk size as the breaking condition instead? - this causes program to exit too early
       //first frame in each message is the sender identity
       zframe_t *identity = zframe_recv( router );
       if (!identity)
       {
           printf("no identity, breaking.\n");
           break; //if we can't find an id, we're all set
       }
       //second frame is 'fetch' command
       char *command = zstr_recv (router);
       assert (streq (command, "fetch"));
       free (command);

       //third frame is chunk offset in file
       char *offset_str = zstr_recv (router);
       size_t offset = atoi (offset_str);
       free (offset_str);

       fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq:frame 4\n", time_str );
       //fourth frame is max chunk size
       char *chunksz_str = zstr_recv (router);
       size_t chunksz = atoi (chunksz_str);
       free (chunksz_str);

       //read chunk of data from file
       fseek (file_to_xfer, offset, SEEK_SET);
       byte *data = malloc (chunksz);
       assert (data);

       //send resulting chunk to client
       size_t size = fread (data, 1, chunksz, file_to_xfer);
       zframe_t *chunk = zframe_new (data, size);
       zframe_send (&identity, router, ZFRAME_MORE);
       zframe_send (&chunk, router, 0);
       chunkNum++;
   }
   if ( 0 == fclose( file_to_xfer ) )
   {
      printf("file_to_xfer closed successfully. \n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("failed to close file_to_xfer. Exiting.\n");
      return -1;
   }
      return 0;
}
```

Here's the client function:

```
void
zmq_receive_file()
{
   FILE *fp_out = fopen ("/usr/vos/bin/testdata_out","w");
   if ( NULL == fp_out )
   {
       printf( "fp_out pointer is NULL.\n");
   }
       return;
   }

   zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new ();
   void *dealer = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_DEALER);
   zsocket_bind (dealer, "tcp://*:6000");
   //up to PIPELINE number of chunks can be in transit
   size_t credit = PIPELINE;
   size_t total = 0; //total bytes received
   size_t chunks = 0; //total chunks received
   size_t offset = 0; //offset of next chunk request
   int chunkNum = 0;

   while (true)
   {
       while (credit) //ask for next chunks until credit is 0
       {
           printf("%s : ft_server has credit, requesting next chunk...\n", time_str);
           zstr_sendm (dealer, "fetch");
           zstr_sendfm (dealer, "%ld", offset);
           chunkNum++;
           chunks++;
       }

       zframe_t *chunk = zframe_recv (dealer);
       if( !chunk )
       {
           break; //shut down and quit
       }
       //if there IS a chunk, write it to testdata_out
       else
       {
           size_t bytes_in_frame = zframe_size( chunk );
           char *data = zframe_data( chunk );
           fwrite( data, bytes_in_frame, 1, fp_out );
       }

       time_str = asctime( timeinfo );
       chunks++;
       credit++;
       size_t size = zframe_size (chunk);
       total+=size;

       if (size < CHUNK_SIZE)
       {
           printf ( "%s : Chunk smaller than CHUNK_SIZE, all done.\n");
           break; //last chunk received, exit

//program exits and leaves server hanging and waiting for an identity, so it never exits
       }
   }
   fclose( fp_out );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The read in your server is blocking, i.e it will only return if a message was actually received.

Here are a couple of options to get the behavior you want :

1. Get the client to send a 'shutdown' message (much like you send a 'fetch' message) when its finished and then add logic to the server when processing the 2nd frame so it breaks out of the loop on receipt of this shutdown message.
2. Change the server to do a non-blocking receive call (check out zpoller and zloop) and deal with the absence of messages correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the tips - do you know of any examples of zpoller and/or zloop for czmq that you could point me to?

Comment: I Couldn't find any examples of usage within a while loop, but there is an example of basic usage here : http://api.zeromq.org/czmq3-0:zpoller. You'll need to set the 2nd argument of zpoller_wait to something positive (its a timeout in ms) and then the return value of zpoller_expired tells you it it times out rather than receiving a message.